# Can't remove my software center

Tags: 13.10, software-center

So I was told that `sudo apt-get remove software-center` would be used to remove software-center, and then I would reinstall it. Well, every time I try to remove it i get this:

```
lacy@lacy:~$ sudo apt-get remove software-center
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Could you read my last post?

Comment: You have another package manager running. `lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` should tell you which process is locking the database. But think twice before doing that...

Comment: @Rmano can your please read my last post

Comment: @Austin read Rmano's last comment =). I think you should ask as to the problem you are having, in linux re-installing rarely fixes anything (although it can on rare occasions).

Comment: Ok... We'll @Rmano it says bash: var/lib/dpkg/lock: no such file or directory      Not to mention my main issuer is adobe flash, it's not 100% installed and it says to remove it in store, but then it freezes

Comment: @Austin: I do not know where "your last post" is --- no time to read all the posts here. About lsof, it seems you forgot the first "/".

Comment: Ok, ill try it... And it was software-center error

Comment: It's says 'permision denied' so I added sudo andbit said command not found